# Replace lang-rust for prettify

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Google doesn’t maintain code-prettify. Things like my patch for proper Rust support—https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/375—just get ignored. Could you guys take [my `lang-rust.js`](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/375/files#diff-1) and use it anyway? I’m tired of the dodgy Rust syntax highlighting (most notably, lifetime syntax (`'identifier`) is understandably handled poorly).

Comment: Hmm. I think it might be time for SE to fork and start maintaining its own prettifications, if there isn't actually any current maintainer. Then maybe we can add PowerShell and some others, finally.

Comment: I've updated the `rust` tag on Stack Overflow already. You'll have to ask for the association on CR on [meta.codereview.se].

Comment: *Sigh.* Bounty offered, still nothing happened…

Comment: Wow, https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/375 was finally merged! Staying with upstream but updating will now work.

Comment: I now defer to just [updating code-prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264356/update-code-prettify).