# Update code-prettify

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

There have been certain changes in [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) which it’d be nice to have used on Stack Overflow *et al.* The primary matter I care about is [the Rust highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259491/replace-lang-rust-for-prettify) because the one currently used handles lifetimes really badly, but there have been changes to other lexers too fairly recently which it might be desirable to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prettify has been updated to [revision 9c3730f409](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/9c3730f40994018a8ca9b786b088826b60d7b54a), the update is rolling out in build rev 2016.7.4.4702 on Meta SE/SO and in build rev 2016.7.4.3725 on sites.